# Implementing Conditions in a Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

So the environment I'm working with is MS SQL Server Management Studio and it's proving to be quite the pain with triggers. What I'm trying to do is create a trigger that inserts a new employee's information in a new table(SALARY_VIOLATION_NEW_EMP) if they have a lower salary than all other employees in the department they are assigned.

I have it where it's inserting new information into the new table, I just can't figure out how to implement the condition. This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SALARY_VIOLATION
ON  EMPLOYEE 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

declare @newFname varchar(50), @newLname varchar(50), @newSsn char(9), @newSex char(1),
        @newSalary decimal(10,2), @newSuper_ssn char(9), @newDno int;

select @newFname = Fname,
       @newLname = Lname,
       @newSsn = Ssn,
       @newSex = Sex,
       @newSalary = Salary,
       @newSuper_ssn = Super_ssn,
       @newDno = Dno from inserted;

INSERT INTO SALARY_VIOLATION_NEW_EMP(FirstName,LastName,Ssn,Sex,Salary,Super_ssn,Dno)
    values(@newFname, @newLname, @newSsn, @newSex, @newSalary, @newSuper_ssn, @newDno);

END
GO
```

To save some time I have test data which satisfies both tables:

```
insert into EMPLOYEE values ('John',null,'doe','234536779',null,null,'M', 20000,'987654321',4)
```

Comment: For future reference MySQL is a different Database Engine.

Comment: What field from your insert has the department information is it DNO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with Triggers is much more fun when you DON'T populate variables, and instead take a set-based approach.

```
INSERT INTO MyNewTable (ColumnList)
SELECT ColumnList
FROM Inserted
WHERE SomeCondition=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If Dno is you department Number then:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER SALARY_VIOLATION
 ON  EMPLOYEE 
 AFTER INSERT
 AS 
 BEGIN

 declare @newFname varchar(50), @newLname varchar(50), @newSsn char(9), @newSex char(1),
    @newSalary decimal(10,2), @newSuper_ssn char(9), @newDno int;

 select @newFname = Fname,
   @newLname = Lname,
   @newSsn = Ssn,
   @newSex = Sex,
   @newSalary = Salary,
   @newSuper_ssn = Super_ssn,
   @newDno = Dno from inserted;

 declare @MinSalary decimal(10,2)
 select @MinSalary = min(Salary) from [EMPLOYEE] where Dno = @newDno and Ssn != @newSsn

 if @MinSalary > @newSalary
 begin

 INSERT INTO SALARY_VIOLATION_NEW_EMP(FirstName,LastName,Ssn,Sex,Salary,Super_ssn,Dno)
     values(@newFname, @newLname, @newSsn, @newSex, @newSalary, @newSuper_ssn, @newDno);
 end;

 END
```

GO